# Split pandas labels of series into indexes and columns for new dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, series

I have a pandas series that looks like this in python:

```
a.1    10
a.2    20
b.1    30
b.3    40
```

And I would like to turn it into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    1    2    3
a  10   20    -
b  30    -   40
```

Would anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `MultiIndex Series` first by `split` and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s.index = s.index.str.split('.', expand=True)
df = s.unstack()
print (df)
      1     2     3
a  10.0  20.0   NaN
b  30.0   NaN  40.0
```